# MongoDB auto updates between posts and comments vice versa

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a web application, and I am spending so long time to take care of updates between related documents.

For example, I have 'Task' document and 'User' document. When task is made, multiple users will be assigned to it. Thus,

```
taskA.assigned = ["1321231fsdfsdf"(userA's _id), "12312313asdasdasd"(userB's _id)]
userA.tasks = [..., "1231321"(taskA's _id),...]
userB.tasks = [..., "12313211"(taskB's _id),...]
```

I could handle it well when it comes to just creating tasks. However, it becomes too tricky when I am going to edit tasks. If user B is deleted from taskA, I have to delete userB's id and go to the userB's tasks property and delete taskA's id too.

Is there any shortcut and automatic way to deal with it? Thank you for your time to read it. Let me know if I was too vague, I will add more detail.

Comment: Your problem is because the way you design your database. You choose to keep duplicated values in different documents. This will help read from database faster but you have to be careful when write to keep the db consistent. Write operations could be tedious at some points, like yours now, if there are many relations between collections.

To solve this you could consider re-design your db structure with relations between collections.

Comment: @Khang Yeah that's what I felt exactly. I know something's wrong with what I have done. Then, what am I supposed to right now. By the way, as far as I remember, when I was using mysql, there was a very handy way to handle this issue. For example making relationship between posts and comments, if a post is deleted all the comments related to the post would be also deleted together. I was researching if mongodb has the same feature, but I am skeptical about it. Is there anybody who know how to do this in mongodb?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to do this easily and with less lines of codes. Around 100 lines reduced to around 30 lines by doing this.

Long story short, I used 'update()' method and various mongo operators, such as $in, $push, or $pull.

Here is my final codes that are optimized with use of update method.

```
var edit = req.body;
edit.assignedTo = edit.assignedTo.split(',');
var old = req.task;
var idQueries = edit.assignedTo.map(function (x) {
 return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(x);
});
User.update({tasks: old._id}, {$pull: {tasks: old._id}}, {multi: true}, function () {
 // Update to remove original task's id from users assigned to it. 
 User.update({_id: {$in: idQueries}}, {$push: {tasks: old._id}}, {multi: true}, function () {
  // Update to add edited tasks'id to new users assigned to it.
  old.lastAction = 'edited';
  old.edited = true;
  old.editedAt = Date.now();
  old.titke = edit.title;
  old.desc = edit.desc;
  old.dueBy = edit.dueBy;
  old.assignedTo = edit.assignedTo;
  old.save(function (err, task) {
   if (err) return next(err);
   User.populate(task, 'assignedTo', function (err, task) {
    res.json(task);
   });
  });
 });
});
```

Wish this help some people!

Answer (score 1):

In a relational database like MySQL using foreign keys and cascade updates could be done automatically, but in MongoDB that's not possible.

But I see in the tags you are using Moongose, so using a [post save hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-post) could do the trick. You can set a hook that updates automatically the user collection each time a task is updated, or viceversa.

---

Other option would be changing your data estructure, but this depends on your case, there are some facts to take into account. I think we don't have enough information to judge, but there are many resources speaking about data normalization in MongoDB, you can check for example the official [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/).

Comment: I feel like I chose mongodb without careful research on its usage. I am pretty sure mysql would be better choice for my project...  By the way, thanks for your answer. It helped me understand a lot.